# How do I save API request array to database in Laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, api

After a successful request, I get the following results in mpesaresponse.json.
In body dictionary body there is **Item** array and that is where I am having a problem.

**Result with dictionary and array inside**

```
{"Body":
    {"stkCallback":
    {"MerchantRequestID":"7261-447082-1",
        "CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_25112020180504486167",
        "ResultCode":0,
        "ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.",
        "CallbackMetadata":{
                            "Item":[
                                    {"Name":"Amount","Value":2.00},
                                    {"Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber","Value":"OKP6V2AB0W"},
                                    {"Name":"Balance"},
                                    {"Name":"TransactionDate","Value":20201125180518},
                                    {"Name":"PhoneNumber","Value":25472566887}]
                            }
    }
    }
}
```

**Controller That receive the callback request**

```
public function MpesaRes(Request $request)
     {
        
        $callbackJSONData=file_get_contents('php://input');
        $callbackData=json_decode($callbackJSONData);
        $resultCode=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->ResultCode;
        $resultDesc=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->ResultDesc;
        $merchantRequestID=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->MerchantRequestID;
        $checkoutRequestID=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CheckoutRequestID;

        $amount=$callbackData->stkCallback->Body->CallbackMetadata->Item[0]->Value;
        $mpesaReceiptNumber=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item[1]->Value;
        $balance=$callbackData->stkCallback->Body->CallbackMetadata->Item[2]->Value;
        $b2CUtilityAccountAvailableFunds=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item[3]->Value;
        $transactionDate=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item[4]->Value;
        $phoneNumber=$callbackData->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item[5]->Value;

        $result=[
            "resultDesc"=>$resultDesc,
            "resultCode"=>$resultCode,
            "merchantRequestID"=>$merchantRequestID,
            "checkoutRequestID"=>$checkoutRequestID,
            "amount"=>$amount,
            "mpesaReceiptNumber"=>$mpesaReceiptNumber,
            "balance"=>$balance,
            "b2CUtilityAccountAvailableFunds"=>$b2CUtilityAccountAvailableFunds,
            "transactionDate"=>$transactionDate,
            "phoneNumber"=>$phoneNumber
        ];
       
       MpesaTransaction::unguarded(static function() use ($result) {
           MpesaTransaction::create($result);
        });


       
}
```

And I am not getting any error

Comment: can you try with save() while storing into database

Comment: I have tried that one but its not workinf

Comment: make it fillable columns in model

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh how?

Comment: can you provide your model  MpesaTransaction

Comment: $model = new MpesaTransaction;
$model->fillable() 
try this @Edwin